# hbase map-reduce job with oozie for best performance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to run a Hbase TableMapReduce job from oozie scheduler.
I have a driver, mapper and no reducer class. What is the best way to run this job from oozie with max-performance of hadoop ecosystem.
Currently I am using an Java action for the driver class in oozie workflow.

```
<action name="custom-java-action-mr">
    <java>
        <main-class>com.mr.sample.MyJobDriver</main-class>
        <capture-output/>
    </java>
    <ok to="fork1"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>
```

Is using it as map-reduce action will have benefits ?
If yes then help me with example .

```
Job job = Job.getInstance();

job.setJobName("My Custom Job");

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(NullOutputFormat.class);

job.setJarByClass(MyJobDriver.class);
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(Entity.FAMILY_NAME));
scan.setCaching(10000);
scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(Entity.TABLE_NAME, scan,
        MyJobMapper.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class, job);
```

Currently Hbase connection is not secure , but we do have hbase secure connection in production env.
Thanks

Comment: Scan of hbase will never required a reducer phase

Comment: @UserSx : yes we did't used reducer, mapper had the complete logic of mr .